# ViewModel type architecture from Controller to View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a fairly complex class of Policies, of which I display a checkbox list of them, the user checks which one they want, and returns back to the server via ajax.  The class is fairly complex:

```
public class Policy {
  public int PolicyId { get; set; }
  public string PolicyName { get; set; }

  ... another 15 properties ...
}
```

To display the list of checkboxes I really only need the Id and Name, so I've created a lightweight class PolicyViewModel that is simply:

```
public class PolicyViewModel {
  public int PolicyId { get; set; }
  public string PolicyName { get; set; }
}
```

So I then pass a List to the View and get a List back containing the selected Policies.

Another developer on my team said that he doesn't necessarily want to translate from the ViewModel to the Policy class on the Ajax call to save the selected policies, but I'm resistant to send a List of policies due to how heavy they are to send to the view, retrieving all the properties, etc.

EDIT: For clarification, on the Ajax save method, to persist to the DB, the call needs a list of the full Policy class.

What is the best way to display this list and get back the values?  Is there a better way than I am proposing?

Comment: Why would one translate something *from* ViewModels at all? Do you need something more than just selected policy ID list to save selection?

Comment: It has everything to do with what you actually NEED back.  Is the only thing required on the ajax call is the list of PorlicyIds?

Comment: Usually, `policies.Select(x => new { PolicyId = x.PolicyId, Name = x.PolicyName};` when sending, and return back only the selected Ids, so `var checked = policies.Where(x => returnIds.Contains(x.PolicyId));` boom. done.

Comment: Good questions, I've revised my question, will need a list of the full class on the Ajax call, so will need to loop through list to get the full class.

Comment: Why does it need a FULL policy class?  Are you duplicating policy's in the database?  Typically it's just a reference to the Policy which only needs the Id.  What is the the design for Database Access (Repository, Straight Entity Framework, etc)?

Comment: @MarkKadlec, your revision does not sound right. If object already exists in the database, you should not need anything else other than its ID to reference it in other table.

Comment: is Policy  class domain object?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain very well, but I like what @Will proposed, rather than a separate class, will simply have a property to List<int> to map back to on the Ajax send, and send via dynamic select as proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you wouldn't need a separate model when serializing to json.  Simply pluck out what you need from the domain object into an anonymous object.

```
return policies.Select(x => new { PolicyId = x.PolicyId, Name = x.PolicyName});
```

on the return trip, you shouldn't have to send anything more than the Ids of the policies that the user selected.  Those can be easily mapped back to your policy objects.

```
public Whatever PostPolicyChoices(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var checked = _context.Policies.Where(x => returnIds.Contains(x.PolicyId)); 
    // snip
```

boom. done.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend you not to work with Domain objects in your mvc application . You must work just with ViewModels, I think  this is best practice for mvc projects. Take a look at [Automapper](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/) and use it in your project, this will simplify your work, so this should look something like this :

in your **[HttpGet]** method you will have :

```
var model =Mapper.Map<IList<Policy>,IList<VmSysPolicy>>(yourlist)
```

And in your **[HttpPost]** method you will have :

```
var domainList=Mapper.Map<IList<VmSysPolicy>,IList<Policy>>(modelList);
```

And in your mapping configuration you will do :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Policy,PolicyVmSysPolicy,>()
.ForMemeber()//Your mapping here
```

and

```
Mapper.CreateMap<VmSysPolicy,Policy>()
.ForMemeber//mapping here
```

Comment: Thanks MDDDC, we do have a domain model and this Automapper sounds like a good way to go since we are just starting the project.  Should make the mapping a breeze, but what if you need to do some sort of transform in the mapping process?

Comment: Automapper provides a lot of things like custom resolvers , and something like that that will make your work more easier...